# Can't change Settings for a Scrapy Spider

Tags: python, scrapy, settings

I'm trying to start a scrapy crawler from a request with some parameters:

```
 msg_req_obj = MessageRequestObject(azureServiceBus=self.azure_service_bus,
                                        sbReqQ=self.sb_request_queue,
                                        sbResQ=self.sb_response_queue,
                                        session=message_body['session'],
                                        studyName=message_body['studyName'], 
                                        studyId=message_body['studyId'], 
                                        strategyId=message_body['strategyId'],
                                        requestId=message_body['requestId'],
                                        email=message_body['email'],
                                        crawlDepth=message_body['crawlDepth'],
                                        crawlPageCount=message_body['crawlPageCount'],
                                        sites=site_obj_array,
                                        msg=message)
```

This message basically passes the first URLs to start a spider, along with 2 settings that will change for each created spider: **crawlDepth** and **crawlPageCount**.

I have the following methods for getting settings:

- settings.py file containing the "default" settings for the spider.

```
    DEPTH_LIMIT = 3
    DEPTH_STATS_VERBOSE = True
```

- config_settings.py file that I use for adding settings to the whole project, including some settings to be used for overriding settings.py.

  ```
  def depth_limit(self):
  _default_depth_limit = 4
  if (self._depth_limit):
      try:
          return int(self._depth_limit)
      except Exception as ex:
          logger.error('"DEPTH_LIMIT" is not a number in application settings. Using default value "' + str(_default_depth_limit) + '"')
          return _default_depth_limit
  else:
      print('"DEPTH_LIMIT" not found/empty in application settings. Using default value "' + str(_default_depth_limit) + '"')
      return _default_depth_limit
  ```
- `custom_settings` inside the spider that overrides `settings.py` file with the settings found in the `config_settings.py`.

```
     custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': configurationSettings.obey_robotstxt,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': configurationSettings.depth_limit,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': configurationSettings.download_delay_for_requests,
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': configurationSettings.max_responses_to_crawl
    }
```

- getting the settings via `get_project_settings()` to retrieve the default settings, then updating it with the `settings.update()` method, passing the values that come from `msg_req_obj` and then starting a `crawlerRunner` with these updated settings:

```
    def crawl_sites(self, blob_config, site_urls, msg_req_obj):
        print("SPIDER STARTED")
        print(site_urls)
        s = get_project_settings()
        s.update({
            "DEPTH_LIMIT" : msg_req_obj.crawlDepth,
            "MAX_RESPONSES_TO_CRAWL" : msg_req_obj.crawlPageCount,
        })        
        self.runner = CrawlerRunner(s)
        self.runner.crawl(GenericSpider, 
                    blobConfig=blob_config, 
                    msgReqObj=msg_req_obj,
                    urls=site_urls)

        deferred = self.runner.join()
        deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
        reactor.run()
```

this last one effectively changes the settings that are going to be passed to `crawlerRunner`. But the spider does not load these settings and starts with `DEPTH_LIMIT=1`.

I tried hardcoding different values for DEPTH_LIMIT in all the other methods (`settings.py`, `config_settings.py` and `custom_settings`), but none of them seem to work, as the spider always crawls up to items with depth=1 before stopping and closing. So it appears that the spider is not taking any of these settings and "defaulting" to DEPTH_LIMIT = 1.

What am I missing? are there any additional steps that I should take in order to be able to implement this?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code for my `crawlProcess` class:

```
class CrawlProcess(object):
    """description of class"""

    def __init__(self, blob_service, blob_service_output_container_name):
        """
        Constructor
        """        
        self.blob_service = blob_service
        self.blob_service_output_container_name = blob_service_output_container_name
        settings_file_path = 'scrapy_app.scrapy_app.settings' # The path seen from root, ie. from crawlProcess.py
        os.environ.setdefault('SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', settings_file_path)
        self.runner = ''

    def spider_closing(self, spider):
        """Activates on spider closed signal"""
        print("STOPPING SPIDER")
        self.runner.join()

    def crawl_sites(self, blob_config, site_urls, msg_req_obj):
        print("SPIDER STARTED")
        print(site_urls)
        s = get_project_settings()
        s.update({
            "DEPTH_LIMIT" : msg_req_obj.crawlDepth,
            "MAX_RESPONSES_TO_CRAWL" : msg_req_obj.crawlPageCount,
        })        
        self.runner = CrawlerRunner(s)

        self.runner.crawl(GenericSpider, 
                    blobConfig=blob_config, 
                    msgReqObj=msg_req_obj,
                    urls=site_urls)

        deferred = self.runner.join()
        deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
        reactor.run()

    def start_process(self, site_urls, msg_req_obj):
        blob_config = BlobConfig(blob_service=self.blob_service, blob_container_name=self.blob_service_output_container_name,)

        crawl_sites_process = mp.Process(target=self.crawl_sites, args=(blob_config, site_urls, msg_req_obj), daemon=True)

        print("STARTING SPIDER")
        crawl_sites_process.start()
        crawl_sites_process.join()
        print("SPIDER STOPPED")
        print("ENGINE STOPPED")
```

here is the code for my `GenericSpider`:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from urllib.parse import urlparse
try:
    from scrapy_app.scrapy_app.items import HtmlItem
except ImportError:
    from scrapy_app.items import HtmlItem

import re
import os
import json
from scrapy_splash.response import SplashJsonResponse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy_app.scrapy_app.utils import get_domain_from_url, get_subdomain_from_url
import logging
from config_settings import ConfigurationSettings
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class GenericSpider(CrawlSpider):
    extractor = LinkExtractor()
    crawl_depth = 0
    name = 'generic'
    configurationSettings = ConfigurationSettings.getInstance()
    handle_httpstatus_list = configurationSettings.handle_http_statuses
    handle_httpstatus_all = configurationSettings.handle_all_http_statuses
    custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': configurationSettings.obey_robotstxt,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': configurationSettings.depth_limit,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': configurationSettings.download_delay_for_requests,
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': configurationSettings.max_responses_to_crawl
    }


    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logging.basicConfig(
           filename='scraping.log',
           format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
           level=logging.INFO
       )

    def __init__(self, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        self.crawler = crawler
        self.blobConfig = kwargs.get('blobConfig')
        self.msgReqObj = kwargs.get('msgReqObj')
        self.urls = kwargs.get('urls')
        self.allowed_domains = [urlparse(url).netloc for url in self.urls]
        self.start_urls = self.urls
        self.proxy_pool = self.configurationSettings.proxies

        self.suggestedKeywords = self.configurationSettings.suggested_keywords


        self.rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), allow_domains=self.allowed_domains,
                                         canonicalize=True, unique=True,), 
                           follow=True, callback="parse_item", process_request="use_splash_request"),]

        self._follow_links = True
        self._domain = ""

        self.failed_urls_dict = {}
        for httpstatus in self.handle_httpstatus_list:
            self.failed_urls_dict[httpstatus] = []


        super(GenericSpider, self).__init__(crawler, *args, **kwargs)


    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        # settings = crawler.settings
        return cls(crawler, *args, **kwargs)

    def parse_item(self, response):

        # if self.handle_httpstatus_all or response.status not in self.handle_httpstatus_list:              # Without this line, ALL HTTP Responses are handleds
        item = self._get_item(response)
        yield item

def _get_item(self, response):

        children = []
        # Get parameters from the Response
        _domain = response.meta['url_domain'] if 'url_domain' in response.meta else get_domain_from_url(response.url)
        _subdomain = get_subdomain_from_url(response.url, _domain)
        _comparableId = response.meta['comparableId'] if 'comparableId' in response.meta else 'NA'
        root = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=urlparse(response.url))
        _html = response.text
        base_tag = response.css("head base").extract()
        if not base_tag:
            _html = _html.replace("</head>", "<base href=\"" + root + "/\"></head>")

        #Populate Child pages List
        links = self.extractor.extract_links(response)
        [children.append(link.url) for link in links]


        item = HtmlItem(
            url=response.url,
            domain=_domain,
            subdomain=_subdomain,
            html=_html,
            description='',
            title='',
            is_suggested=str(False),
            comparable_id=str(_comparableId),
            is_error=str(False) if 200 <= response.status < 300 else str(True),
            http_status=response.status,
            crawl_depth=response.meta['depth'],
            child_pages=children
        )

        self._set_title(item, response)
        self._set_description(item, response)
        self._is_suggested(item)

        return item

    def _set_title(self, item, response):
        if isinstance(response, SplashJsonResponse) or response.meta['isFirstPage'] == True:
            title = response.css("title::text").extract()
            if title:
                item['title'] = title[0].encode("utf-8")
        else: 
            pass

    def _set_description(self, item, response):
        if isinstance(response, SplashJsonResponse):
            meta_description = response.css("meta[name=\"description\"]::attr(content)").extract()
            if meta_description:
                item['description'] = meta_description[0].encode("utf-8")

    def _is_suggested(self, item):
        #logger.info('TITLE-DESCRIPTION:- %(title)s ==> %(desc)s', {'title': item['title'], 'desc': item['description']})
        _title = item['title'].decode("utf-8") if item['title'] else ''
        _description = item['description'].decode("utf-8") if item['description'] else ''
        try :
            if any(re.search(r'\b' + sug_kwd + r'\b', _title, re.IGNORECASE) for sug_kwd in self.suggestedKeywords) \
              or any(re.search(r'\b' + sug_kwd + r'\b', _description, re.IGNORECASE) for sug_kwd in self.suggestedKeywords):
                item['is_suggested'] = str(True)
        except Exception as ex:
            template = "GenericSpider:- An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            ex_message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print(ex_message)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Gallaecio thanks, I edited the question and added both the code for the spider and the crawlProcess.

Comment: My point was that you should create the smallest piece of code that can be used to reproduce your issue, removing anything that is irrelevant to the question. Short questions with minimal verifiable code examples significantly increase the chance of getting an answer, and often in the process of producing a minimal verifiable example you may find the root issue. Now your question is even longer than before :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I managed to get it to work, turns out that the crawler was initiating with my custom settings, but it did not pass any following requests after depth = 1.